# Best way to compare nested dictionaries in a list, Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm querying a public endpoint to get an exchange rate of varies exchanges that returns a list with nested dictionaries.  I'm most interesting in is the key "amount" field in the nested dictionaries.  I'm struggling to come up with a solution to store the nested dictionary that has the most "amount" value in a variable.  Any ideas would be extremely helpful.  I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

Here is the list:

```
list_with_nested_dicts = [{"partner":"simpleswap","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"simpleswap","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"stealthex","amount":37.90346104,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":66.62083333333334,"fixed":true,"min":39.91443225,"max":2550.215226,"exists":true,"id":""},{"partner":"stealthex","amount":37.20972396,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":23.158333333333335,"fixed":false,"min":77.82938688,"max":25209.49720665,"exists":true,"id":""},{"partner":"godex","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":0,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"changenow","amount":37.2077365,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":11.08859649122807,"fixed":false,"min":56.60646516,"max":25259.88795509,"exists":true,"id":""},{"partner":"changelly","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":1,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"changelly","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":1,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"instaswap","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"exolix","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":0,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"fixedfloat","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"switchain","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"changehero","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":56.41111111111111,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"changehero","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":2.4833333333333334,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"binance","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"nexchange","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"letsexchange","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"letsexchange","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":0,"fixed":false,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""},{"partner":"alfacash","amount":0,"currency":"cel","supportRate":3,"duration":0,"fixed":true,"min":0,"max":0,"exists":false,"id":""}]
```

The dictionary that has the most amount is:

```
{"partner":"stealthex","amount":37.90346104,"currency":"cel","supportRate":2,"duration":66.62083333333334,"fixed":true,"min":39.91443225,"max":2550.215226,"exists":true,"id":""}
```

Comment: Just FYI, the example you've posted (and most likely is a string-representation of what the endpoint is giving you) seems to be JSON, and should be decoded into a Python-object before trying to find the "amount" of any of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
from operator import  itemgetter
res = max(list_with_nested_dicts, key=itemgetter("amount"))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'partner': 'stealthex', 'amount': 37.90346104, 'currency': 'cel', 'supportRate': 2, 'duration': 66.62083333333334, 'fixed': True, 'min': 39.91443225, 'max': 2550.215226, 'exists': True, 'id': ''}
```

From the documentation:

> The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that
> used for list.sort()

Note there is no need to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), you could simply use a lambda function as the value of `key`:

```
max(list_with_nested_dicts, key=lambda x: x["amount"])
```

Additionally, in case some of the dictionaries have no item `"amount"`, I suggest you use [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as follows:

```
default = 0
res = max(list_with_nested_dicts, key=lambda x: x.get("amount", default))
```

where `default` should be a value that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Bu you will need to replace 'true' with True and 'false' with 'False' for this code to work.

```
list_with_nested_dicts.sort(key=lambda a: a['amount'])
print(list_with_nested_dicts[-1])
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient it sorts all the list only to get the maximum.